what is best way of replicating sumifs but by creating an array formula?
I have the following data set:

and I have the following table:

what I would like to do is create an array formula in the table that would remove the need for many sumifs formulas (such as =SUMIFS(D$10:D$18,$A$10:$A$18,$A3,$B$10:$B$18,"y",$C$10:$C$18,"y")) that would need to be dragged across and down so that we would end up with this:


Try using MAKEARRAY() --> simple and easy to understand:


=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(A13:A15),COLUMNS(B12:M12),LAMBDA(r,c,
 SUM((INDEX(A13:A15,r)=A2:A10)*(B2:B10="Y")*(C2:C10="Y")*(INDEX(B12:M12,c)=D1:O1)*D2:O10)))


Or, Use one single dynamic array formula to return the whole array:
=LET(
     _Data, DataTable[#All],
     _Name, DROP(TAKE(_Data,,1),1),
     _Headers, DROP(TAKE(_Data,1),,3),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(_Name),
     _Output, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_Uniq), COLUMNS(_Headers), LAMBDA(r,c,
     SUM((INDEX(_Uniq,r)=_Name)*(INDEX(_Headers,c)=_Headers)*
     (INDEX(DROP(_Data,1),,2)="Y")*(INDEX(DROP(_Data,1),,3)="Y")*DROP(_Data,1,3)))),
     VSTACK(HSTACK(A1,_Headers),HSTACK(_Uniq,_Output)))


If applicable, then can use GROUPBY() as well:


=VSTACK(HSTACK(A1,D1:O1),
 GROUPBY(A2:A10,D2:O10,SUM,,1,,BYROW(B2:C10="Y",AND)))


After lot of trials and error found this one to be quicker and efficient than the rest :
=LET(
     _Conditions, MMULT(N(Conditions="Y"),{1;1})>1,
     _Filter, FILTER(HSTACK(IDData,Vals),_Conditions,""),
     _Name, TAKE(_Filter,,1),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(_Name),
     _SumVals, MMULT(N(_Uniq=TOROW(_Name)),DROP(_Filter,,1)),
     IFNA(INDEX(_SumVals,XMATCH(ID,_Uniq),B1:M1),0))



Thank you. I couldn't get the ETA Lambda one to work and I don't yet have Groupby. The others worked for small data sets but alas not for the size of data that I have (c. 50k rows) as kept crashing my laptop. I might need to rethink how I do this

@andyleary to have GROUPBY() you will need to enable the Office Insiders as well as for the ETA Ok, I will try another option !

@andyleary can you try this one and let me know: =LET(      _Conditions, MMULT(N(B2:C10="Y"),{1;1})>1,      _Filter, FILTER(HSTACK(A2:A10,D2:O10),_Conditions,""),      _Name, TAKE(_Filter,,1),      _Uniq, UNIQUE(_Name),      VSTACK(HSTACK(A1,D1:O1),HSTACK(_Uniq,MMULT(N(_Uniq=TOROW(_Name)),DROP(_Filter,,1)))))

@andyleary honestly for larger datasets, i personally go for Power Query and dont rely on formulas.

@andyleary Sir, I did some speed test on my end with 55K rows of data, it doesnt crash on my end. You can download the excel from here also, I am using a gaming PC and Laptop, could be a difference in performance, infact the output was in within a sec of time. like blink of an eye!

that formula works as well, but again not for large data sets. I have made attempts to use power query before but again, I have found speed issues when comparing to using formulas within excel itself. Maybe I should have another go at it. Hey ho. It is all a good learning curve

sorry, there was an error in my file that was causing the delays. I can now confirm the formulas work for the data set size. However, the latter formulas don't reference A13:A15 which they would need to do as potentially there could be the name "D", which would need to return zero. Is this possible? The first formula does this but not for large data sets by the looks of it : =MAKEARRAY(ROWS(A13:A15),COLUMNS(B12:M12),LAMBDA(r,c,
SUM((INDEX(A13:A15,r)=A2:A10)(B2:B10="Y")(C2:C10="Y")*(INDEX(B12:M12,c)=D1:O1)*D2:O10)))

@andyleary the latter formulas are one single dynamic array formula, it will return the whole array so no need to write down manually, a, b, c, d etc. Also, click on the here i did some speed test works without any issues, if you have the excel, i will try to run some speed test, just remove the private information's.

@andyleary also it better to transform the source ranges into Structured References that is Tables it will help the formulas to auto adjust when new rows are added/removed!

how do I send you the excel?

@andyleary just create a one drive link or google drive link or dropbox link or any cloud drive, and post in the following comments.

https://1drv.ms/x/s!Apl0h-1TIjwvyRYOfSQ_RkHux2BU

does this work?

Yes it does. i will update you brb!

What is the use of Column D do i need to account that as well?

column d is not needed for the formula

Oh okay understood. Give me a moment i am updating.

@andyleary Hi Sir, I have updated with another formula it will be bit quicker. I have tested on desktop version, just applied on the web.

This is the updated formula, comparatively faster than the earlier one. =LET(      _Conditions, BYROW(Conditions,LAMBDA(α,AND(α="Y"))),      _Extract, FILTER(HSTACK(IDData,Vals),_Conditions,""),      MAKEARRAY(ROWS(ID),COLUMNS(Headers),LAMBDA(r,c,SUM((INDEX(ID,r)=INDEX(_Extract,,1))*DROP(_Extract,,1)))))

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
